# Commutators and Commutator Subgroup Equality

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is soluble and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/N$ is soluble. The proof I'm trying to understand uses induction. However, I have hit a wall.

I'm stuck on the following equality:

$$ \langle [g,h]N :  g,h \in G\rangle = [G,G]N / N $$

$[g,h]$ is the commutator: 
$$[g,h] = g^{-1} h^{-1} g h $$

$[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup:
$$\langle [g,h] :  g,h \in G\rangle$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can prove the equality by showing (i) the group on the left contains the set $[G,G]N/N$, (ii) $[G,G]N/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.  You just need to keep using the key property of a normal subgroup $N$, namely that $gN = Ng$ for every $g \in G$.